# I have one contact in SF that works for one customer, but is now helping with another customer...how do I add her to the second customer's contacts?

Tags: salesforce

I have a contact in SalesForce, she works for a PE group, and is attached to one customer, but is also helping answer questions for another customer.  I tried to add her in the second customer's contacts, and it said she was a duplicate, but I can't figure out how to attach her to both accounts.  Any direction on where I can learn to do that?  Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Contacts can be connected to accounts directly (parent-child, via Contact.AccountId lookup) and indirectly (many-to-many, [AccountContactRelation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_accountcontactrelation.htm)). It's useful when contact has multiple functions, for example being Director in 1 company and VP of Sales in another.Check the page layout, you might have to add a related list.

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/accounts_contacts_lightning_experience/understand-account-and-contact-relationships-lightning might be a good start